# Amazon EC2 still uses the old code, not the newly deployed one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am deploying code with Capistrano, this is the content of `deploy.rb`:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, "project_name"
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:my_name/fileito.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
#set :deploy_via, :copy

set :user, "deployer"
set :password, "password"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/project_name"
#set :app_site, "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" 
set :app_site, "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

role :web, app_site                     # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, app_site                     # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  app_site, :primary => true   # This is where Rails migrations will run

require 'capistrano-unicorn'
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:reload' # app IS NOT preloaded
after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:restart'  # app preloaded

set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano/recipes"

# Added:
after "deploy:stop", "deploy:start"
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do
    run "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"
  end
  task :stop do
    run "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
  end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

But when I deploy the new code and check the app in the browser, I see there still the old code. What's wrong? When I take a look into the `current` directory, there is the new code - I manually checked the files through the **cat** command.

How is possible that in browser is still the old version -> the old code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try restarting your app server?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons that this can happen.  Here are a few links you should check:

[Unicorn continues to use old code following deploy + restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578687/unicorn-continues-to-use-old-code-following-deploy-restart)

[Unicorn restarting in old release directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198840/unicorn-restarting-in-old-release-directory)

[Restarting Unicorn with USR2 doesn't seem to reload production.rb settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388074/restarting-unicorn-with-usr2-doesnt-seem-to-reload-production-rb-settings)